# bash command with escaped TAB ('\t') character fails in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, escaping, gnu-make

In a Makefile (gnu make, on an Ubuntu system), I have the following commands:

```
.PHONY: stack-use
stack-use: $(BUILD_PATH)/$(TARGET).elf
    @cat build/*.su | sort -t$$'\t' -k2 -nr | awk -F'\t' '{ if($$2>0) {print $$0}}' | column -s$$'\t' -t
```

When running `make -n stack-use`, I get

```
$ make -n stack-use 
cat build/*.su | sort -t$'\t' -k2 -nr | awk -F'\t' '{ if($2>0) {print $0}}' | column -s$'\t' -t
```

and running the printed command produces the output I want.

However, the problem is that when I run it from within make, I get:

```
sort: multi-character tab ‘$\\t’
```

So it seems that the backslash character gets escaped, and the shell command therefore does not 'see' the intended TAB ('\t') character but a backslash followed by a 't'.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: based on the suggestion below, the final working code is

```
    @cat build/*.su | sort -t"$(printf '\t')" -k2 -nr | awk -F'\t' '{ if($2>0) {print $0}}' | column -s"$(printf '\t')" -t
```

Comment: `make` doesn't use `bash` by default; it uses `sh`, which in Ubuntu is `dash`. `dash` doesn't support `$'...'`-quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments note, you are not using bash here.

You can either force your makefile to use bash as its shell by adding this:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Or you can rewrite your command to use POSIX-conforming syntax.  For example maybe replace `-t$$'\t'` with `"-t$$(printf '\t')"`.

Comment: Less readably, you can also use your editor to force a literal tab character into your script, rather than a digraph for some other command to convert to a literal tab character.

Comment: Yes, but I would be wary of this because it means every time you (or anyone else) saves this file they have to consider whether their editor is replacing tab with space.  A good editor will understand that in a makefile you shouldn't do that, but some don't (and maybe some understand that only a TAB as the first character on the line is important to make).